# I am trying to use PHP to connect to my mongodb database but I can't find a way to make it work

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to use playground to test my code but a error pops up saying that I need to connect to the database

```
<?php
    
    const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&directConnection=true&ssl=false";
    
    // Select the database to use.
    //use('db_NolonoloDef');
    
    db.t_account.insert({"nome":"giulio cesare","cognome":"pippolone"});
    db.t_account.find();
    
    //SELECT * FROM t_account
    //db.t_account.find();
    //db.t_account.count();
    
    //SELECT * FROM t_account WHERE [condizione]
        try{
            $conn = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        } catch (MongoDBDriverExceptionException $e) {
            echo 'Failed to connect to MongoDB, is the service intalled and running?<br /><br />';
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: That ... doesn't look like valid PHP code

Comment: I changed the code to <?php
  // connect to mongodb
  $m = new MongoClient();
  echo "Connection to database successfully";
  // select a database
  $db = $m->db_NolonoloDef;
  echo "Database  selected";
?> and it still is not working

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, hard to read. Instead, [edit] your question and add the code there. What does "_it still is not working_" mean? Do you get any errors? Blank page? Also post any errors you get in your question

Comment: fyi, the PHP documentation has a chapter on [MongoDB](https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) and some [Tutorials](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.php), did you read/follow those?

Comment: Here is an example, a blog post, about [using php and MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/php-crud/) - connecting to the database and perform basic crud operations.

Comment: Yes I did, I also put the mondo.dll file in php.ini, sorry for the code but you guessed right, I'm an absolute newbie, desperate for help since I don't have much time to complete the project. The error I am getting displays in playground in VSC, it says that I need to connect to a database

Comment: Will it still work? (I am using compass) I don't know where to get the username and password